# Typescript, Array to dynamic key Object , how set return types?

Tags: typescript

How to set this function return type?

```
function arr2ObjByKeys(range: [string, string], keys: { start: string; end: string }) {
  return {
    [keys.start]: range[0],
    [keys.end]: range[1]
  }
}
```

For example:

```
arr2ObjByKeys(['a', 'b'], { start: 'start1', end: 'end1' })
```

I hope vscode intelligent tip: start1 and end1

Answer (score 0):

If keys are not fixed then you can define return type as

```
type arr2ObjReturnType = {
    [x: string]: string;
}
```

as use it as below:

```
function arr2ObjByKeys(range: [string, string], keys: { start: string; end: string }) : arr2ObjReturnType{
  return {
    [keys.start]: range[0],
    [keys.end]: range[1]
  }
}
```

Otherwise, it is fixed start1 and end1 then you can directly add them in type as

```
function arr2ObjByKeys(range: [string, string], keys: { start: 'start1'; end: 'end1' }) : arr2ObjReturnType{
  return {
    [keys.start]: range[0],
    [keys.end]: range[1]
  }
}

type arr2ObjReturnType = {
    start1: string;
    end1: string ;
}
```

Comment: When keys is not fiexed, ```ts: type arr2ObjReturnType = { [x: string]: string; } ```, Still no intelligent tip